# Web: how to redirect to a CodePen or JsFiddle with information filled?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, codepen

I am writing a Js parser, which has contents of three files: HTML, JS and CSS. following code is an example of my JS variables:

```
var html = '<div class="box"></div>';
var css = '.box{height: 200px; width: 200px; background-colour:red;}';
var js = 'window.alert("Here we go!");'
```

CodePen and JsFiddle are most commonly used online IDE. I wonder if I can **redirect** to either of the page, **with HTML CSS JS text areas filled with my variable**, so the user will be able to edit the code themselves.

I am not sure if it's tangible. I will be glad if someone point a direction.
I do appreciate for your help.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lwgk4c5/ which is described in https://docs.jsfiddle.net/api/display-a-fiddle-from-post.

Comment: Just start a new session, type in your values and then click on the 'Share' button. It will furnish you with a link.

Comment: @Tommy You could post that as an answer, it's spot on as far as I can see.

Comment: @Thomas: I posted it as an answer.

Comment: [codepen redirect](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/prefill/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following (retrieved from https://docs.jsfiddle.net/api/display-a-fiddle-from-post):

```css
body { font-family: Helvetica, Tahoma; }
h2 { font-size: 1.5em; margin-bottom: 10px; display: block;}
p { margin-bottom: 15px; display: block; font-size: 0.8em; }
label { font-weight: bold; }
textarea, input[type=text] { 
    padding: 3px 5px; 
    width: 80%; 
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
textarea { height: 70px; }
```

```html
<h2>Load a fiddle based on the POST variables</h2>
<form method='post' action='http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/mootools/1.3/dependencies/more/' target='check'>
    <p><input type='submit'/> - fiddle will be loaded in different browser window/tab.</p>
    <select name="panel_html">
        <option value="0">HTML</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name='html'><p class="red">It's magic!</p>
<p><a href="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/api/post.html">Documentation</a></p></textarea>
    <select name="panel_js">
        <option value="0">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="1">CoffeeScript</option>
        <option value="2">JavaScript 1.7</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name='js'>window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  $$('p.red').each(function(el) {
      el.setStyle('color', '#00ff00');
  });
});</textarea>
    <select name="panel_css">
        <option value="0">CSS</option>
        <option value="1">SCSS</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name='css'>p {font-family: Helvetica, Arial; }</textarea>
    <label>Title:</label>
    <input type='text' name='title' value='some title'/>
    <label>Description:</label>
    <textarea name='description'>descr</textarea>
    <label>Resources (comma separated, no spaces):</label>
    <textarea name='resources'>http://abc.it/xyz.js</textarea>
    <label>DTD:</label>
    <input type='text' name='dtd' value='html 4'/>
    <label>Wrap (l/d/h/b)</label>
    <input type='text' name='wrap' value='l'/>
</form>
```

Have also a look at the linked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lwgk4c5/